# Is possible to make Multiple flutter pages in one app?

Tags: flutter

I went to convert book to android app the book has 100 page ,
should I create page(activity) for each page ? or any other ways to do this?

Comment: You definitely shouldn't use a screen for each page. Instead, create a Widget that supports pagination.

Comment: Have a single screen and just change the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You can use `PageView` or its `builder` constructor for this, here is the basic example

```
PageView.builder(
  itemCount: 100,
  itemBuilder: (_, index) => YourPage(list[index]),
)
```

---

**Update:**

Create two widgets like this.

```
// It only shows Text
class TextPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  const TextPage({@required this.text});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(text, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20));
  }
}

// It only shows Image from assets
class ImagePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String image;
  const ImagePage({@required this.image});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Image.asset(image);
  }
}
```

Now in your main class, use them as

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: PageView(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextPage(text: "This screen only has text"), // 1st screen only text
        ImagePage(image: "assets/images/chocolate_pic.png"), // 2nd screen only image
        Column( // 3rd screen will have both
          children: <Widget>[
            TextPage(text: "This is the text followed by an image"),
            ImagePage(image: "assets/images/chocolate_pic.png"),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Kindly delete all previous comments, and you don't need to send me your book, if you can tell me how are you planning to make app with book, it would make more sense, currently I am assuming you have text and images in the book, for text you have `String` and for images, you will have images in `jpg`, `png` format. If I am wrong, do let me know how you are planning to make the app out of the book.